# Execute code only while debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Is it possible to run specific code only when I am debugging the program via the debugging tools of Visual Studio?

If I use `#if DEBUG` or `Conditional(“DEBUG”)` the code is still triggered when running the .exe in the /Debug directory.

Comment: Visual studio runs the exe in the debug folder too, it just attaches a debugger. The conditional code is compiled in.

Comment: See this for a couple of solutions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101806/check-if-application-was-started-from-within-visual-studio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `#if DEBUG` is for Conditional Compilation, it does not affect execution at runtime.

Instead use `Debugger.IsAttached` to branch at runtime.

Comment: Thanks - is this suitable for running Unit Tests too though?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, the statements beginning with a hashtag are pre-processor directives. These directives are not present in the Translation Unit; thus these conditional statements do not exist in the compiled file.

**EDIT** It seems that this whole translation unit thing doesn't apply for C#

Comment: I'll be a pedant: it's "hash symbol"', "pound symbol", or "number sign" and not "hashtag". And the concept of Translation Units does not apply to the C# compiler.

Comment: @Dai Well, I was being a bit informal about the "hash symbol"; but I was unaware of the condition of translation unit for C#. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Dai To be a pedant as well, the official name is actually "octothorpe". :P